# How to create a corner in sketch using VBscript in CATIA ?

Tags: vba, catia

I've been trying to create a corner between two lines in sketch, but I could not find any command for it.

Is there any way to create a corner between two lines??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Title says `VBScript`. Tagged as `[vba]`. Which is it?

Comment: Have you tried `Factory2D` from the Sketch? You might not be able to make a corner, but you could draw a line, then an arc, and then another line via `Factory2D`.

Comment: @Bond it is Scripting in CATIA

Comment: @GisMofx  yes I tried it becomes complicated and we have to mention every Point..im tryin to draw sketch only with the length of the line as input

Comment: I think it might be your only option with VBA, but doable. You can even add tangent and coincident constraints while you're at it.

Answer (score 0):

CHALLENGE ACCEPTED!!!

Language = vb.net

Assuming lines do not cross (but can touch each other)

Assuming oPart as part already defined

Assuming hb1 as GeometricalSet already defined

Assuming BasePlane as Plane of sketch already defined

Assuming oSel as Selection of ActiveDocument already defined

Assuming spa as SPAWorkbench =CATIA.ActiveDocument.GetWorkbench("SPAWorkbench") already defined

```
 Public Sub Test()
        Dim oSke As Sketch = hb1.HybridSketches.Add(BasePlane)
        Dim f2D As Factory2D = oSke.OpenEdition()

        Try
            Dim lc1 As Line2D = f2D.CreateLine(0, 0, 0, 10)
            Dim lc2 As Line2D = f2D.CreateLine(20, 0, 10, 10)
            DrawCornerWithoutTrim(oSke, f2D, lc1, lc2, 5)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(ex.ToString())
        Finally
            oSke.CloseEdition()
        End Try
        oPart.UpdateObject(oSke)
    End Sub

    Public Sub DrawCornerWithoutTrim(oSke As Sketch, f2D As Factory2D,
                                    Line1 As Line2D, Line2 As Line2D,
                                    Radius As Double)

        Dim c1(1), c2(1)
        Dim b1(1), b2(1)
        Dim vRef = spa.GetMeasurable(Line1).GetMinimumDistance(Line2)

        Dim refPoint1 As Point2D
        Dim refPoint2 As Point2D

        Dim C As Constraint
        Line1.StartPoint.GetCoordinates(c1)
        Line1.EndPoint.GetCoordinates(c2)

        Line2.StartPoint.GetCoordinates(b1)
        Line2.EndPoint.GetCoordinates(b2)

        If Math.Round(spa.GetMeasurable(Line1.StartPoint).GetMinimumDistance(Line2.StartPoint) - vRef, 4) = 0 Then
            refPoint1 = Line1.StartPoint
            refPoint2 = Line2.StartPoint
        ElseIf Math.Round(spa.GetMeasurable(Line1.StartPoint).GetMinimumDistance(Line2.EndPoint) - vRef, 4) = 0 Then
            refPoint1 = Line1.StartPoint
            refPoint2 = Line2.EndPoint
        ElseIf Math.Round(spa.GetMeasurable(Line1.EndPoint).GetMinimumDistance(Line2.StartPoint) - vRef, 4) = 0 Then
            refPoint1 = Line1.EndPoint
            refPoint2 = Line2.StartPoint
        ElseIf Math.Round(spa.GetMeasurable(Line1.EndPoint).GetMinimumDistance(Line2.EndPoint) - vRef, 4) = 0 Then
            refPoint1 = Line1.EndPoint
            refPoint2 = Line2.EndPoint
        End If

        c1(0) = (c1(0) + b1(0) + c2(0) + b2(0)) / 4
        c1(1) = (c1(1) + b1(1) + c2(1) + b2(1)) / 4

        Dim Fix1 As Constraint = oSke.Constraints.AddMonoEltCst(catCstTypeReference, Line1)
        Dim Fix2 As Constraint = oSke.Constraints.AddMonoEltCst(catCstTypeReference, Line2)


        Dim CenterPoint As Point2D = f2D.CreatePoint(c1(0), c1(1))
        CenterPoint.Construction = True

        C = oSke.Constraints.AddBiEltCst(catCstTypeDistance, CenterPoint, Line1)
        C.Dimension.Value = Radius

        C = oSke.Constraints.AddBiEltCst(catCstTypeDistance, CenterPoint, Line2)
        C.Dimension.Value = Radius

        CenterPoint.GetCoordinates(c1)

        Dim Arc As Circle2D = f2D.CreateCircle(c1(0), c1(1), Radius, 0, 1)
        C = oSke.Constraints.AddMonoEltCst(catCstTypeRadius, Arc)
        C.Dimension.Value = Radius

        C = oSke.Constraints.AddBiEltCst(catCstTypeTangency, Arc, Line1)
        C = oSke.Constraints.AddBiEltCst(catCstTypeTangency, Arc, Line2)

        Dim ct1 As Constraint = oSke.Constraints.AddBiEltCst(catCstTypeOn, Arc.StartPoint, Line1)
        Dim ct2 As Constraint = oSke.Constraints.AddBiEltCst(catCstTypeOn, Arc.EndPoint, Line2)


        If spa.GetMeasurable(Arc).Length > 3.14 * Radius Then
            Change = True
            osel.Clear()
            osel.Add(ct1)
            osel.Add(ct2)
            osel.Delete()
            ct1 = oSke.Constraints.AddBiEltCst(catCstTypeOn, Arc.EndPoint, Line1)
            ct2 = oSke.Constraints.AddBiEltCst(catCstTypeOn, Arc.StartPoint, Line2)
        End If
        osel.Clear()
        osel.Add(Fix1)
        osel.Add(Fix2)
        osel.Delete()
    End Sub
```